# Rebooting ESXi build 4.0.0, 193498 Lost Network on Guests

Tags: vmware-vsphere, vmware-esxi, host

I have two ESXi hosts one running esxi build 4.0.0, 193498, and the other esxi build 4.0.0, 208167. These servers are identical HP DL 385 G5p with 64GB of Physiscal RAM, and almost a terabyte of local-drive space.

esxi build 4.0.0, 208167 = Host A
esxi build 4.0.0, 193498 = Host B

Last week I rebooted both hosts, and Host A came up, and then subsequently I began to power the guest VM's one -by-one. All of the guest came up with no issues. However, the same was done with Host B, but its guest VM's seemed to have lost their place on the network. Their IP settings were fine, I could not ping ANYTHING either via IP or DNS. I restarted the Network Management Agent/Service, and to no avail.

Ultimately the fix for this was to remove the Windows Server 2003 R2 SP2 hosts from the domain, then reboot the ESXi server!, and then rejoin the domain and reboot the Guest VM host. Following this the VM Guest would be able to see the network. I had to do this 3 seperate times for each of he VM guests on the ESXi host. I do not feel what I did to fix the VM guest was legit, not sure if it was rebooting the VM, the Host, or the whole Domain remove\rejoin that fixed things.

Once I would get one Guest to work I had to do it ALL-OVER again for the other two guests, each time I reboot the ESXi server I feared I would break the other guest I just repaired. Luckily that was NOT the case and the guest once repairedremained working.

Has anyone else ever experienced this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe a MAC address conflict? Check all your adapters and settings inside the VIclient... Also check for IP address conflicts: Maybe you use DHCP but some of your guests have static IPs assigned within the DHCP range.